# Problem with stripe Webhook not seem to be called?

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments, endpoint

help !!!  i have a problem with stripe Webhook not seem to be called ...
i setup endpoint in Stripe dashboard for live website

and create route in my app like so

```
app.post(
  '/webhook-checkout',
  bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json' }),
  orderController.webhookCheckout
);
```

pointing to ...

```
exports.webhookCheckout = (req, res, next) => {
  const signature = req.headers['stripe-signature'];

  let event;
  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      req.body,
      signature,
      process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send(`Webhook error`);
  }

  if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed'){
    createOrderCheckout(event.data.object);
    }
  res.status(200).json({ received: true });
};
```

and i got Nothing when payment session complete

Comment: There are a couple of things that you can try. First, you would want to check if the webhook event delivery was attempted. You check this by locating an event from your dashboard [1]. Second, what type of webhook did you create: Account or Connect? [2]. Is your webhook in test-mode or live-mode and are you creating these checkout sessions in live-mode or test-mode?

[1] https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/events
[2] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/webhooks

Comment: hi thanks for your comment , yes i setup all and event type connect  in test mode and its lestining but nothings happing

Comment: I'd recommend reaching out to Stripe Support with as much as information that you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem and just solved it .
Here is the solution :

1. You need to make sure you have installed the stripe cli in vscode .reference :https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-vscode

2.open a terminal run : **npm start**

3.open another terminal run: **stripe listen --forward-to=localhost:5000/stripe**   (remember to replace the port num ,in my case is 5000)

4.open the las terminal run : **stripe trigger customer.created**

You can get the clear tutorial here :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLHvHUWd2ug&t=100s

Comment: Thanks, for me it was the fact that i was closing the terminal in which stripe was forwarding requests to my server